# Enabling monetization during YouTube API Upload

Tags: youtube-api, ads

I'm trying to enable monetization during a YouTube API upload. I have set my default preferences to always set the monetization flag which it does when uploading through the Youtube.com website, but it is ignored when uploading via the API.

We're expecting thousands of videos to be uploaded by our user community in a short amount of time, and it will be impractical to manually switch every video via the Youtube.com website.

If this isn't supported with the default YouTube API, is there a business development person we can talk to in order to see if there is a different partner level that would give us access to this feature?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a YouTube support issue, not programming.

Answer (score 1):

Your API uploads should act the same. Please reach me with your info, so I can verify.

Comment: I am experiencing the same problem with the youtube api, did you find a resolution?

Comment: I have the same problem too. How do you set usage policy when uploading via API?

Comment: I have confirmed still that via the Data API, uploads do not respect the default monetization settings. This should be fixed, to allow users to set their own monetization toggle through the API.

Comment: 2017 API still doesn't respect default monetization preferences. I have a similar use case, where I upload over 500+ videos a day. Is there any solution for this?